# Wildcard match a string in an array using the -notlike operator in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell, operators, wildcard

Making a wildcard match in a string is simple using the `-like` operator:

```
$myString = "abcdefghi"

if ($myString -like "*ef*") {
  return $true
} else {return $false}
#Returns: True
```

And it also works on arrays like this:

```
$myArray = @("abc", "def", "ghi")

if ($myArray -like "*ef*") {
  return $true
} else {return $false}
#Returns: True

if ($myArray -like "*xyz*" ) {
  return $true 
} else {return $false}
#Returns: False

if ($myArray -like "*efg*") {
  return $true
} else {return $false}
#Returns: False
```

As you can see in the last example, the statement did not evaluate to true, so we can assume the `-like` operator applies the wildcard match to every item in the array individually, which is great. (the `g` i `efg` is in the next item)

But here comes the kicker; the `-notlike` operator does not follow any of the logic above!

```
$myArray = @("abc", "def", "ghi")

if ($myArray -notlike "*ef*") {
  return $true 
} else {return $false}
#Returns: True

if ($myArray -notlike "*xyz*") {
  return $true 
} else {return $false}
#Returns: True
```

No matter what string you try to match it always returns true.

Weirdly enough if you use the `-not` operator to negate a statement with a `-like` operator the logic works.

```
$myArray = @("abc", "def", "ghi")

if (-not($myArray -like "*ef*")) {
  return $true 
} else {return $false}
#Returns: False

if (-not($myArray -like "*xyz*")) {
  return $true 
} else {return $false}
#Returns: True
```

This solution is probably the best way to go about this, but it's not very legible and it's frustrating not being able to use the `-notlike` operator intuitively. You could cast the array into a string and use the `-notlike` operator but then you miss out on the functionality that each item is matched individually. Although when you cast an array into a string the items are separated by a space so it kind of works...:

```
$myArray = @("abc", "def", "ghi")

if ([string]$myArray -notlike "*ef*") {
  return $true 
} else {return $false}
#Returns: False

if ([string]$myArray -notlike "*efg*") {
  return $true 
} else {return $false}
#Returns: True

if ([string]$myArray -notlike "*ef g*") {
  return $true 
} else {return $false}
#Returns: False
```

So my questions are:

- Is there any way I can use the `-notlike` operator to validate if a wildcard match does not exist in any item of an array?
- If not, What is the cleanest way to validate if a wildcard match does not exist in any item of an array. I have tried the `-notmatch`, `-notcontains` and `-notin` operators as well but neither works to accomplish my goal.

Comment: It seems you have already found a good answer negating the result from filtering with `-like` that's a good way of doing it. You could also negate `.Any` from Linq or check `.All` also with Linq. Cleaner is so subjetive specially in a language that supports so many different ways to accomplish the same objective

Comment: "it's not very legible and it's frustrating not being able to use the -notlike operator intuitively" -- Your intuition seems to be wrong here. `-notlike` checks whether any of the items in the array is not like the pattern. So because `abc` is not like `*ef*`, it returns true. This is the same way that `-like` works too, i.e. it returns true when `def` matches the pattern, even though the other ones don't. Negating `-like` is indeed the best solution for checking that there are no matches at all.